# Handle cancelled task and task exceptions in Task.WaitAll?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using TPL to crawl a set of Urls and then do some processing.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var tuple = list[i];
    string url = tuple.Item2;

    tasks[i] = httpClient.GetStringAsync(url).
        ContinueWith(task => {
        {
            ......

        });
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

The issue is that at the `Task.WaitAll` statement it seems it will often throw exceptions because a task has been cancelled. I understand that `httpClient.GetStringAsync` may not always ensure success so I want to add a retry logic in `httpClient.GetStringAsync` when exceptions occur. What will be the proper approach to do this?

Comment: If the retry failed, do you still want an exception?

Comment: @I3arnon: I do. But then the exception will be passed as AggregateException to Task.WaitAll. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, because a task may contain several exceptions. If you would `await Task.WhenAll` that was built for `async-await` then you would get the actual exception inside (the first one that is).

Comment: @I3arnon: The issue is that I'm using this function in Main() so I cannot use await Task.WhenAll..

Comment: You can use `Task.WhenAll(...).GetAwaiter().GetResult()` if that's critical.

Comment: *I understand that httpClient.GetStringAsync may not always ensure success* what does that mean? What is the exception you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily wrap a retry around `GetStringAsync` with a `for` loop that tries until there's no exception or the retry limit is reached. I store the task and extract the result from it using `await` so if the retry limit was reached without success, the exception would be rethrown:

```
async Task<string> GetStringAsync(HttpClient client,string url, int retries)
{
    Task<string> task = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < retries; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            task = client.GetStringAsync(url);
            await task;
            break;
        }
        catch
        {
            // log
        }
    }

    return await task;
}
```

You could even have that as an extension method on `HttpClient`:

```
static async Task<string> GetStringAsync(this HttpClient client, string url, int retries);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `async/await` you can use following extension method as a starting point.

```
static class HttpClientExtentions
{
    public static Task<string> GetStringWithRetryAsync(this HttpClient client, string url, int retries)
    {
        var completion = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        var ex = new List<Exception>();

        Task<string> getString = client.GetStringAsync(url);
        Action<Task<string>> continueAction = null;
        continueAction = (t) =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                ex.Add(t.Exception);

                if (retries-- > 0)
                {
                    getString = client.GetStringAsync(url);
                    getString.ContinueWith(continueAction);
                }
                else
                {
                    completion.SetException(new AggregateException(ex));
                }
            }
            else // assume success, you could also handle cancellation
            {
                completion.SetResult(t.Result);
            }

        };

        getString.ContinueWith(continueAction);

        return completion.Task;
    }
}
```

Use it this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var tuple = list[i];
    string url = tuple.Item2;

    int retryCount = 3;
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(); // should create new object for each req
    tasks[i] = httpClient.GetStringWithRetryAsync(url, retryCount).
        ContinueWith(task => {
        {
            //......

        });
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```